# Hash efficiency

Tags: hash, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I want to store pxq bytes of data in a hash.

Which is more efficient  ?

A hash with pxq entries storing a single byte each 
or
a hash with p entries each storing q bytes of data

Keys are sparse memory addresses

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store second values as a q bytes in hash, but just a reference to them stored somewhere else in memory.
 But still, the first idea is to use stl::map.